# Best practice - exporting CSV

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv, export

I am looking for the best way to export a CSV file. With MySQL and PHP. 
Currently Im generating an CSV with INTO OUTFILE, it works that way but I don't think it's the good way.

Isn't there a better option to make a CSV export download button for every moment a user clicks the download button?

- A INTO OUTFILE export is only possible for one instance and is not overwritable.

I have to generate a timestamp and save the file, and then get the latest file from my directory.

This method looks a bit messy for downloading a CSV file from a server... 
Has anyone got better solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use PHPExcel for generating csv file on button click and can save file or can download without save

Comment: PHPExcel will write CSV, but if it's simply CSV from PHP (rather than INTO OUTFILE) then fputcsv() or SplFileObject are far easier and more efficient

Answer (score 0):

I think you are well off with exporting via `INTO OUTFILE`. The reason is that sending the content to the CSV file is done by the MySQL server. Doing it with the PHP Script would be slower (first of all because it is a script, second of all because the data from the SQL server need to be passed to the script) and cost you more resources.

If the CSV file(s) become large you should keep in mind that your Script still may expire. You can encounter this issue by either setting an higher value for the maximum running time of a script in the configuration or have the CSV file being created by an external process/script

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
`echo $query | mysql > $unique`;
$contents = file($unique);
```